# RichTextBox XAML not loading

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, xaml

I have this `Xaml` for my RichTextBox which was generated by a `WinForms` application.

The `Xaml` needs to be displayed in `Silverlight` using a RichTextBox but it is not displaying anything.

When I use a trycatch and display the error it just shows me an `ArgumentException` and the message is "value"

```
   <Section xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
  <Paragraph FontSize="16pt"><Run>Windows 8 downloads </Run>
  </Paragraph>
  <List MarkerStyle="Disc">
    <ListItem>
      <Paragraph>
        <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/buy">Update to Windows 8.1</Hyperlink>
      </Paragraph>
    </ListItem>
    <ListItem>
      <Paragraph>
        <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/downloads">Free downloads</Hyperlink>
      </Paragraph>
    </ListItem>
    <ListItem>
      <Paragraph>
        <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/internet-explorer/download-ie">Internet Explorer</Hyperlink>
      </Paragraph>
    </ListItem>
    <ListItem>
      <Paragraph>
        <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.bing.com/explore/desktop">Desktop wallpaper from Bing</Hyperlink>
      </Paragraph>
    </ListItem>
  </List>
  <Paragraph FontSize="16pt"> 
  </Paragraph>
</Section>
```

**C# Implementation**

```
        try
        {
            rtf.Xaml = xamlRtfCode; //"<Section xml:space="preserve" xm.........";
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.GetType().ToString() + " - " + e.Message);

        }
```

I changed the XAML code to that of below and I now have a different error
(see screenshot) - I have no idea what is causing this.

New Xaml code I tried

```
<Section xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"><Paragraph><Run FontSize="20" /></Paragraph><Paragraph><Run> </Run></Paragraph><Paragraph><Run FontSize="20" /><Run /><Run /></Paragraph><Paragraph><Span><Run FontFamily="corbel" FontSize="4px"> </Run></Span></Paragraph><Paragraph><Span FontFamily="corbel" FontSize="4px"><Span><Span><Span><Run FontSize="20">Hello world</Run></Span></Span></Span></Span></Paragraph><Paragraph><Run FontFamily="corbel" FontSize="4px" /><Run /><Run /><Run /></Paragraph></Section>
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

When I remove the FontSize attribute from the above Xaml the Content displays fine in my RichTextBox. So there is something not right with the Xaml Code.

Comment: rtf.Xaml? That doesn't look like Silverlight.

Comment: the rtf is the name of the <RichTextBox> control - Only just started using SL and I was originally expecting to use the original RTF format.

Comment: I mean `XAML` property is not available in a `Silverlight` RTB? correct me if im wrong.

Comment: Its there for me, Im using Silverlight 5 if that makes any difference

Comment: What's the inner exception? If there's one

Comment: When I try to display the InnerException.Message the SL just will not load at all

Comment: Do you have `XamlReader.Parse`? Parse it and then just add it to the rtb blocks

Comment: Check my update, When I removed the fontsize attribute the content displayed.